# href attribute set, javascript sees as empty string

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am experiencing odd behaviour in Chrome (v43.0.2357.134) whereby I am reading an anchor element's `.href` attribute, but in specific circumstances its value is an empty string.

I would like the `.href` value to be populated on all anchors.

### Issue

Specifically, this is what is being observed:

```
//Bad (unwanted) behaviour
var currentElem = ; //Code to pick out an anchor element
console.info(currentElem.href); //"" (empty string)
console.info(currentElem.getAttribute('href'); //"path/to/other/page.html"
```

[image]

*Edited to add/clarify: Note that in this screenshot, at the point of reaching the fourth line of code the value of `nextPageUri` is an empty string (otherwise would not have reached the `debugger;` line). The fifth line then populates `nextPageUri` with the `.getAttribute('href')` value, hence the value showing next to line two.*

This is what is (correctly) seen within Firefox, and on the first TWO DOMs via Chrome:

```
//Good (desired) behaviour
var currentElem = ; //Code to pick out an anchor element
console.info(currentElem.href); //"http://example.org/root/dir/path/to/other/page.html"
console.info(currentElem.getAttribute('href'); //"path/to/other/page.html"
```

### Background

Context: This is within a script to inline multiple pages of search results to a single page, and the anchor elements are located within a DOM retrieved via `xmlHttpRequest`. The code runs perfectly via Firefox for >100 pages.

Confusingly, the incorrect behaviour described above only occurs on the third and subsequent requests in the Chrome browser.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with Chromium/Blink-based browsers: if you use `DOMParser` to parse string into a document, `href` properties with relative URI (i.e. doesn't start with http[s]) will be parsed as empty string.

To quote tkent from [Chromium issue 291791](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=291791):

> That's because a document created by DOMParser doesn't have baseURI.  Without baseURI, relative URI references are assumed as invalid.

Same thing happens if you use `createHTMLDocument`. ([Chromium issue 568886](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=568886))

Also, based on [this test code posted by scarfacedeb on Github](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-classic/issues/278), `src` properties also exhibit the same behavior with relative URIs.

As you have pointed out, using `getAttribute()` instead of the dot notation works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome's "element.href" doesn't act any differently on the 3rd try than it does on the first 2 -- you mentioned that you are paginating, when this error happens. how does the "href" attribute on the Next Page link get set each time you arrive at the page? It seems likely that your code to evaluate the element's href attribute is simply running before the href is set -- as evidenced by your debugger being able to evaluate it after a pause.

Try and reproduce this issue in a plunkr.

Comment: You have misunderstood the debugger output - the variable is being set by accessing a different property via line 4 (as opposed to line 2). In particular, note the right-hand side where the watch panel displays `.href` to still equal an empty string despite the pause, while `.getAttribute('href')` has a value (albeit off-screen in the screenshot above).

Comment: Also, the `href` is set via a plain old HTML output (`<a href="">Link</a>`). It fetches page n's HTML, extracts the "next page" url, fetches page (n+1)'s HTML, extracts the "next page" url... etc...

Answer (score 0):

I know you're checking if nextPageUri is empty.

But, could you try always using

```
nextPageUri = currentElem.getAttribute('href');
```

and see if that works?

I experienced a similar problem using a DOMParser for translating `text/html` pages coming from ajax requests and, after that, finding `href`'s of `<a>` elements inside it.

For instructions purpose, this is how I'm using the parser

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
$.ajax({....}).done(function(request){
  var page = parser.parseFromString(request, 'text/html');
});
```

**Test yourself**

If you want to test the behaviour of `.href` and `.getAttribute("href")` yourself, please run this code at chrome dev tools console:

```
parser = new DOMParser(); // create your DOMParser

// the next line creates a "document" element with an <a> tag inside it
parsed_page = parser.parseFromString('<a href="test">click here</a>', 'text/html'); 

link = parsed_page.getElementsByTagName('a')[0]; // locate your <a> tag

link.href; // this line returns ""

link.getAttribute('href'); // this line returns "test"
```